# Strange behavior with variable names and data between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I have a controller that is supposed to write text from an input field to the screen. If I use this controller by itself everything works as expected:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('test', []);

    function OneCtrl() {
        vm = this;
        vm.changeHandler = changeHandler;
        vm.item = "";
        vm.value = "";

    }

    angular
        .module('test')
        .controller('OneCtrl', OneCtrl);



    var changeHandler = function() {
        vm.value = vm.item;
        console.log(vm.item);
    };


})();
```

Try here: http://codepen.io/minuskruste/pen/qdrZqq

However, if I add another controller with the same behavior something really weird happens. First of all, the input from field 1 is not sent to console anymore and the text is also not inserted into the html body. Second of all, when I type something into input field 2 it behaves correctly. If I now go back to field 1 and type there, suddenly field 2 input is output to console, even though controller two was never told to do so! This is controller 2:

```
(function(){


function TwoController(){
    vm = this;
    vm.changeHandler = changeHandler;
    vm.item = "";
    vm.value = "";

}

angular
.module('test')
.controller('TwoController', TwoController);

var changeHandler = function() {
    vm.value = vm.item;
};
```

})();

Try here: http://codepen.io/minuskruste/pen/QbpNdY

Is this normal behavior? I was very surprised by it. I also checked if maybe the `changeHandler()` leaked to global space but since I've put everything in closures that's not the case. Furthermore this is consistent over different platforms i.e. Chrome and FF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue you are having is that you are declaring `vm` without the `var` keyword, which makes it a global variable.

However, `vm` with the `var` keyword is in the local scope of the controller. As a result, it's not available to the `changeHandler()` anymore. If you reorder your code and declare `changeHandler()` inside the controller, it will work.

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('test', []);

  function OneCtrl() {
    var vm = this;  
    vm.item = "";
    vm.value = "";    
    vm.changeHandler = function() {
      vm.value = vm.item;
      console.log(vm.item);
    }
  }  

  angular
  .module('test')
  .controller('OneCtrl', OneCtrl);
})();

(function(){
  function TwoController() {   
    var vm = this;  
    vm.item = "";
    vm.value = "";    
    vm.changeHandler = function() {
      vm.value = vm.item;
      console.log(vm.item);
    }
  }    

  angular
  .module('test')
  .controller('TwoController', TwoController);
})();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test">
  <h1>Choice array</h1>
  <div>
    <form novalidate ng-controller="OneCtrl as one">
      <input type="text" ng-change="one.changeHandler()" ng-model="one.item">
      <div>{{one.value}}</div>
    </form>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form novalidate ng-controller="TwoController as two">
      <input type="text" ng-change="two.changeHandler()" ng-model="two.item">
      <div>{{two.value}}</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're using global "vm" variable, which containg this reference of controller. And with second controller you're overwriting vm variable with reference to second controller.

I've updated your code to use proper this references

Also angular supports another data binding approach with special $scope object: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

```js
(function() {

 angular.module('test', []);

 function OneCtrl($scope) {

  // This construction makes sure I know which context is addressed. I can now hand vm (view-model) inside an object and the context doesn't change.
  this.changeHandler = angular.bind(this, changeHandler);
  this.item = "";
  this.value = "";

 }

 angular
  .module('test')
  .controller('OneCtrl', OneCtrl);



 var changeHandler = function() {
  this.value = this.item;
  console.log(this.item);
 };


})();

(function(){


 function TwoController(){
  
  // This construction makes sure I know which context is addressed. I can now hand vm (view-model) inside an object and the context doesn't change.
  this.changeHandler = angular.bind(this, changeHandler);
  this.item = "";
  this.value = "";
  
 }

 angular
 .module('test')
 .controller('TwoController', TwoController);

 var changeHandler = function() {
  this.value = this.item;
 };


})();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test">

 <h1>Choice array</h1>

 <div>
  <form novalidate ng-controller="OneCtrl as one">

   <input 
   type="text" 
   ng-change="one.changeHandler()" ng-model="one.item">

   <div>{{one.value}}</div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

 </div>

 <div>
  <form novalidate ng-controller="TwoController as two">

   <input 
   type="text" 
   ng-change="two.changeHandler()" ng-model="two.item">

   <div>{{two.value}}</div>
  </form>
 </div>




</body>
```

Comment: Hm, your code is running but you don't give the right answer. Angular supports using `this` as well as `$scope`, so this is not the issue. See trevor's answer for more info.

Comment: I fixed your code using this, just giving more info.

Comment: Yes, you did fix it but the issue was not that I used `vm` but that I overwrote it because I didn't use `var`. You told me I overwrote it. But you also removed the declaration of vm and that was unnecessary and confusing the issue. I'll give you an upvote because you fixed it and it worked but you didn't put a lot of effort in explaining the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article on the Controller As syntax.

http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

If you declare the vm variable in each controller it will prevent the overwriting behavior you are seeing. Javascript is functional scoped, which means if it doesn't find the variable declaration for vm in the current function, it will go up the prototypical chain until it finds the declaration (var vm). If it doesn't find any declaration in the global scope, it will automatically create one for you. By declaring inside each controller you will prevent them from both sharing the same global scope.

```
function OneCtrl() {
    // This construction makes sure I know which context is addressed. I can now hand vm (view-model) inside an object and the context doesn't change.
    var vm = this;
    vm.item = "";
    vm.value = "";

     vm.changeHandler = function() {
      console.log(vm.item);
      vm.value = vm.item;
    };
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KdZvG7d2COLNcjRIfyHb?p=preview

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how this is related to the Controller As syntax. Also, I am actually declaring vm in both controllers. I now see that I'm overwriting `vm` (so you're right about that) but I'm already declaring it inside the controllers.